# Cant use Crypto in SuiteCommerce Advanced Service?

Tags: node.js, netsuite, suitecommerce

My SuiteScript Service `MyService.Service.ss` file is attempting to use the Node.js library `Crypto` but I get the error `Error: No crypto` when I run my service.

Does the Node.js version that SCA uses not have the Crypto library installed? Do I need to explicitly add Crypto as a dependency to `distro.json`? If so where? Do I need to install Crypto? If so, any advice how - I'm new to Node.js.

I am using pretty much standard Crypto functions, see below for the code that causes the problem:

```
function service (request)
{
    'use strict';

    var crypto = require('crypto'); // Error here

    var token = crypto.createHmac('md5', public_key)
               .update(private_key)
               .digest('hex');

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netsuite doesn't use the V8 engine so you are pretty much out of luck with crypto.

I've used [Paul Johnston's md5 package](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/index.html) for hmac calc for years and it is fast enough and interoperates well. Name says MD5 but it includes SHA-1,256,512 as well.

Comment: Thanks :). I did some research and it looks like SCA/NetSuite backend uses Rhino not Node.js. Is that correct? Or maybe Rhino is built partially off Rhino?

Comment: Rhino was what they were using last time some of their stack traces leaked through. I imagine that's still the case since they operate on a Java stack. You can't get at any of the rhino functionality though.

Comment: damn :P I was hoping Rhino has a cryptographic function I could use. I'm probably going to use the node package js-sha256 and install it as a `third_parties` module in my SCA website (and include it in `distro.json`). Hopefully I can pull in that libary that way and use it.